# Compiling iphone app for device - errors

Tags: iphone, xcode, device, exit-code

I've been trying to compile an iPhone app to test on a device, it's properly provisioned and everything, but I'm getting the following error in xcode when I'm trying to build it:

```
 error: can't exec '<com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility>' (No such file or directory)
Command <com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> failed with exit code 71
```

I've been looking around, but can't figure out what the problem is. I've re-downloaded the SDK (including XCode) in the hopes that would fix it, but it hasn't helped. Does anyone know what might cause this?
If you need more info, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same problem here.. And i can't find a solution anywhere.

Update1. Upgrading xcode3.2.3-ios sdk 4.0.1 to xcode3.2.3-ios sdk 4.0.2 did NOT help

Update2. Uninstalling everything ( sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all ) and
reinstalling everything did NOT help.

Update3. Uninstalling everything, THEN completely delete the /Developer directory ( rm -Rf /Developer )
then reinstalling eventually solved this problem. I can now compile and run on my iphone device.

Obviously, de-installing xcode does not remove all elements, in spite of the fact that you specify --mode=all, some pieces are still left behind.

Comment: i am now upgrading to ios 4.0.2 (was on 4.0.1) hope this helps

Comment: I'm trying this right now.
Are you the same person who replied on my thread in the developer forum? (there my user name is Aerion). You should probably reply there too.

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem and solved with the same solution ;) Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can check your App name in the plist file. May be your name have special characters like (underscore _, asterisk, * ). Try your app in the device after removing any special characters in your app name.If, even after this, your app  does not run, check your Project name, and if you have any special characters then remove it.

Comment: The project name has a number in the middle of it, but apart from that is all one word with no special characters. All alphanumeric.
And the app name is the same.  
Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh well, hopefully someone else will. Thanks anyway.